# how to make a macOS app have two main menu

Tags: macos

I know some mac application has two main menu.
`main menu` means top left menu in macOS screen.

When a windowA show, the main menuA show.
As I click some window (name it windowB) in the application
 and another menuB is replaced menuA.
And as I click windowA, the main menuA reappear.

Does someone know how to implement this behavior?

Comment: What application are you thinking of? I haven't seen any macOS applications that did that in a very long time.

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen that app.
Second main menu and window is implemented in some.bundle.
But I think the fact doesn't relate the means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to associate a menu to each window. For this, you can copy the MainMenu of the Application and paste it into the appropriate Window Controller Scene. Then select the connections of the window in the scene and link the item "menu" to the new menu of the scene. Repeat this for all your window controllers/windows.

Then you need to add some code. Create a new Window class:

```
class Window : NSWindow {
    override func becomeKey() {
        NSLog("become2")
        NSApplication.shared().mainMenu = self.menu
        super.becomeKey()
    }
}
```

and then set the class property of each window to this Window class.

You can then edit menus accordingly to your needs. Be aware that you need to reconnect each menu item to the appropriate first responder action...

I'm not sure it is the best solution, but it works well for me. In fact I don't really understand why I need to subclass NSWindow this way...

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
It seems good!
But I can't confirm your result.
Could you upload your sample project to somewhere?

Comment: Easy to find me on the web (use my first and last names) I will send you the code back.

Comment: I confirmed main menu replaced!
You saved me. Thank you.
It is only one flaw that the root menu `test` is not replaced.
But it's environment problem.
My environment is macOS10.12.5 and Xcode8.3.3. 
Or storyboard or swift problem...

Comment: I think you can't replace that one at least it is absolutely not recommended doing so. The first menu must be the one related to the whole application...

Comment: Yea, I think so.
The app I know show another root menu that text is not bold.
I don't know why that text is not bold.
I think the app probably uses an another implementatin method.
Anyway your method fulfill my demand. Thank you.